# How can I modify this VBScript?

Tags: sql, vbscript

Our company runs a mixed environment of Linux and Windows servers (accounts side on Windows, orders side on Linux). We have to synchronise some information about customer accounts between these systems.

Below is one of the scripts that we have scheduled on a Windows server to export customer account information to a text file that then gets picked up by a Linux server and imported.

What I wanted to do, to make the workflow better and to improve the speed was to also do the SQL update on the Linux server from within the script, rather than exporting and then waiting for the Linux server to collect it.

Is it possible?

My experience mainly lies in Linux scripting (bash etc.) but I did manage to write the below script originally with some help.

### Existing script

```
Option Explicit

Dim sDir : sDir = "\\Server\Data"
Dim sCS  : sCS  = Join(Array( _
        "Provider=vfpoledb" _
      , "Data Source=" & sDir _
      , "Collating Sequence=general" _
), ";")
Dim oCN : Set oCN = CreateObject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
oCN.Open sCS
Dim oRS : Set oRS = oCN.Execute("SELECT SN_ANALSYS, SN_CRLIM, SN_CURRBAL FROM " & WScript.Arguments(0) & "_SNAME.DBF WHERE SN_ANALSYS != '' ORDER BY SN_ANALSYS ASC")
Do Until oRS.EOF
   WScript.Echo oRS.Fields(0).value, "50", oRS.Fields(1).Value
   WScript.Echo oRS.Fields(0).value, "51", oRS.Fields(2).Value
   oRS.MoveNext
Loop
oCN.Close
```

### New script

```
Option Explicit

Dim sDir : sDir = "\\Server\Data"
Dim sCS  : sCS  = Join(Array( _
        "Provider=vfpoledb" _
      , "Data Source=" & sDir _
      , "Collating Sequence=general" _
), ";")
Dim oCN : Set oCN = CreateObject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
oCN.Open sCS
Dim oRS : Set oRS = oCN.Execute("SELECT SN_ANALSYS, SN_CRLIM, SN_CURRBAL FROM " & WScript.Arguments(0) & "_SNAME.DBF WHERE SN_ANALSYS != '' ORDER BY SN_ANALSYS ASC")
Do Until oRS.EOF
   //
   // make connection to Oracle SQL server on Linux server
   // run update statement using oRS.Fields
   //
   oRS.MoveNext
Loop
oCN.Close
```

I already have the Oracle Instant Client installed on the Windows server since we use it for other things.

Comment: You can _script_ almost anything you can do from within Windows command line. So provide your how-to _make connection to Oracle SQL server on Linux server_  and how-to _run update statement using oRS.Fields_ (i.e. with that `oRS.Fields(0).value, "50", oRS.Fields(1).Value` and so on). **Please** do not post code snippets in a comment: [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28386925/edit) rather. By the way, consider to _make connection_ once for all updates (out of `Do Until oRS.EOF` loop) only.

Comment: Where did I post code snippets in a comment? This is my first comment.

Comment: Excuse me, please. Intended for a prevent appeal as some posters  (many of them) use doing that though... I beg your pardon if looks a bit impolite (due my poor English?)

Comment: However, you could make connection to Oracle SQL server with a standard connection string, something like `strConnection = "Provider=MSDAORA;User ID=username;Password=password;Data Source=myOracleDB;Persist Security Info=True"`, where `myOracleDB` would be the _TNSNAME_ of the oracle connection and `Provider` might be specific to your environment.